# How do I access this location under the bridge in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I've looked through a few walkthroughs, but have not found an answer on how to reach the Shiney under the bridge (to the right of my character, bottom of screen). This location is under the Dragon midir after the shared grave bonfire. I've tried falling with the cat ring, but it's too far.

How do I access this area?

[image: Bridge]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell from the picture alone but <strike>that seems to be the cave Midir falls in after you attack him enough when he's perched on the bridge.</strike>  
<strike>That said, I don't remember an item there so it might just be a light effect.</strike>

**UPDATE**
I first mistook the floor where the item is for water and though it was

> Midir's boss room

It's actually a small cavern you can access right after the lower bridge. Starting from the Ringed City Streets bonfire, head out toward the Shared Grave, cross the bridge then hug the right wall. You'll soon reach a small hole that leads to the cavern seen in OP's picture. The item is some titanite scales.

Comment: thanks. It's an item for sure, I looked at it from diff angles and saw it as i was falling. I'll try to make my way to midir and see if I can access that area.

Comment: @DustinDavis Oh looking at the picture again, I think I just realised what it really is. When you cross the lower bridge the first time and Midir keeps flying and breathing fire, there's a small passage in the right wall that lead to a small area with an item. From the  Ringed City Streets bonfire, head outside toward the bridge, go across and hug the right wall. Soon you'll see the passage and get to that alcove

Comment: I looked several times on that side, but i'll look again. When I fall down, i can see inside the doorway and it looks like there is a guy sitting on a ledge on the opposite side, but I have not seen an opening on the other side yet. I do see ledges that could potentially be hiding an opening from my view, but they are up high so still no idea how to get to them. I'll look around a bit more though.

Comment: Ok, you're right. It's extended on one side and is very well hidden without hugging the wall. Thank you.